# Where do I put the cables from my soldered l293d onto the arduino uno/arduino pro mini? (Drone)

Tags: motor, drone

I am trying to create a drone but I am struggeling a bit with the components and the schematic. I have 4 small drone motors from hubsan x107 and i have soldered their wires on a l293d driver like this below:

[image]

As you can see i have also soldered jumper cables on the l293d as well and I now look to put them on the arduino uno or a arduino mini pro (i have both at home) but I am not sure where to put these cables in order to make this work. I have typed them out as you can see on the picture and named them: Jumper cable 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 and 8.

This is the hardware I use:

Motor: http://www.banggood.com/Hubsan-H107C-X4-RC-Quadcopter-Spare-Parts-Motor-H107-a23-p-87563.html

Arduino uno

L293D

Cables

Would a setup like this work if I put the jumper cables on the correct pins on the arduino? And if so where on the arduino do i need to connect each wire?

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: I did not down vote you.  But will try to explain why it likely happened.  Your question is way too broad - actually to the point it  can not be answered.  All Arduino project are based on software / firmware.  And if there is none in the question, then there really can be no project.

Comment: Appreciate the feedback! Updated the post with the motor i use. Other then that It is a simple arduino uno board i work with along with the L293D driver that I also linked an image about. And of course cables

Comment: Hint: Most people who write code (drivers?) for the Arduino leave documentation explaining how to use their drivers.  This is to say, you are still leaving out a key piece of information in your question:  What driver are you using?

Comment: L293D driver? Well i only use x4 motors, the L393D and a arduino uno so I guess that is my driver haha :P

Comment: You are missing a huge piece.  There's bare metal programming.  Which is very difficult. But the Arduino paradigm abstracts you from that.  So there is at least the PWM drivers that come with the Arduino software package.  So you need to connect up to the pins that the Arduino will support with the built in PWM Arduino driver. But to control 4 motors for flying is going to take a lot more than that.  What are you using?  Are you writing your own software?

Comment: st2000, I partially agree, I think it's a valid question if you ask how to wire up the circuit. It doesn't need any code for that yet. But I agree: "would this setup work" is too broad, there are many points that may fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fncb5W.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The battery needs to be the right voltage for your motors. There are no specifications on the page you linked to at all, so your job now is to find out what your motors are and what voltage they run from.

Comment: The datasheet has an interesting addition to the ground prins: "Device ground and heat sink pin. Connect to printed-circuit-board ground plane with multiple solid vias."

Comment: @Paul Yeah, I was thinking of mentioning that. Not sure if the OP has a driver on a breakout (in which case it doesn't matter) or if he has directly wired jumpers to the chip pins - in which case he may want to solder on some lumps of metal as well to act as a heat sink...

Comment: Also, I'm curious if you could toggle the enable pin to get "active breaking" then it may be worth to not directly wire them to vcc.

Comment: @Paul That may be vaguely possible, but I wouldn't want to do that through an Arduino IO pin.

Comment: @Paul Actually that might be ok. I think the EN would be isolated from the back EMF from the motor.

Comment: Hmm, the outputs can be "high", " low" and "high impedance". According to the "function table" in the TI datasheet. But I was wondering if high impedance would cause breaking.

Comment: About back EMF, the functional block diagram does show diodes outside the chip itself, but the description says: "high voltage outputs for inductive load driving", so that's indeed not very clear. So when using this part, rather check with TI or just take the neccesary precautions (reverse diode).

Comment: @Paul Or even better, invest in a proper Arduino shield instead of dead-bugging it.

Comment: Agreed, but I was thinking of making an "all in one" robotics board that could be used as an educational tool. So I was wondering if it could be made breaking, but I guess that's a whole other question altogether (and I also think I won't have the time for this in naar future :p). I'll stop here to avoid further discussion that's more aimed on my question as on the person who posted this, though it can be interesting if he needs breaking on his quadcopter.

Comment: @Paul Braking is supposed to be done using just two motors per driver (1+2 and 3+4) with the input pins controlling the direction and the EN pins controlling the speed.